# Converting from semi monthly to Bi-weekly

Tags: paycheck

I am on salary and our pay was recently changed from semi monthly to biweekly on Nov 13,2015, that pay check only reflected the first week on Nov up to the 7th.

As I was looking over my pay stub this week at the year to date, I noticed with one pay check left for the year I will not have met my salary for the year. Is this common?

The way I figured it is that we still should have been paid the same amount because we are past the months which had the extra pay period and Nov and Dec still only had two pay periods each just as if we were on semi-monthly.
I am on Salary not hourly.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what you explained, here is what happened.

- Early November receive the 2nd October paycheck, for all hours through October 31st.
- Pay date: 13 November; End of pay period 07 November
- Pay date: 27 November; End of pay period 21 November
- Pay date: 11 December; End of pay period 05 December

Last check of 2105

- Pay date: 25 December; End of pay period 19 December

  First check of 2016
- Pay date: 08 January; End of pay period 02 January

This is normal. You will get the last part of your December pay in January. In your case there are nine 2015 workdays in the first check for 2016.